# ob_get_contents prints php tags instead of executing the PHP code

Tags: php, string, output-buffering

so I have this code:

```
  $template_file = 'template.tpl.php';
  ob_start();                      // Start output buffering
  include "./$template_file";      // Include the template file
  $contents = ob_get_contents();   // Get the contents of the buffer
  ob_end_clean();                  // End buffering and discard
  return  $contents;
```

this is what template.tpl.php looks like:

```
<?=translate_string('A message to display to user')?>
```

however when I inspect the content of $contents, instead of having it display `'A message to display to user'` it instead displays `<?=translate_string('A message to display to user')?>` ... ie. it displays the PHP code in entirety instead of executing the PHP code and simply return the output of the executed code...

Any idea on what could possibly cause this?

I'm using Drupal 6

### EDIT

looks like short_open_tag setting is On...any other possibilities?

also it would be great if I can still use `<?=` notation without making it `<?php` etc... since it's used quite prevalently

### Further Update

looks like jszobody no longer have further contribution, if anyone else knows what could possibly cause this other than the short_open_tag setting, feel free to answer

thx to jszobody for the short_open_tag contribution

Comment: Possibly you don't have PHP short open tags enabled? Change your template to `<?php echo translate_string(..) ?>`

Comment: Oops, I saw `$template_file` and `ob_get_contents` next to each other and brain saw `file_get_contents. Reading code too much today.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Don't worry, [this is what I saw](http://i.imgur.com/MP2488k.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using PHP short tags in your template code. If those are not enabled on your server, it's not parsed by PHP, and instead treated as plain text.

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

I'd change your template to this:

```
<?php echo translate_string('A message to display to user'); ?>
```

Comment: Semi-colon needed also.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn It is not required when only a single command is given, but I agree it is a good practice to put it there everytime.

Comment: @pillarOfLight Did you try my suggestion anyway?

Comment: @jszobody check out the note on the preference for using <?= ... I know I know, I'd love to use <?php as well but it's not up to me

Comment: @pillarOfLight I simply want to know however if the full php tags _actually worked_ for you. So far you haven't answered that. Then we can see about your preference.

Comment: @jszobody I can't test it right now since it's in a remote server which I currently have no access...I need to brainstorm possible causes of this issue before putting it on the remote server which requires painful bureaucracy handling...

Comment: @pillarOfLight Provide an update then when you can test out the provided answer to your problem. If that doesn't fix your issue, we'll dig some more.